# vga_switcheroo and Intel HD 3000 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: hybrid-graphics, vgaswitcheroo

I'm trying to get vga_switcheroo to enable my integrated Intel HD 3000 instead of my ATI card. My problem is that there is no `vgaswitcheroo` directory in `/sys/kernel/debug/` on my system.

```
> grep -i switcheroo /boot/config-3.2.0-26-generic 
CONFIG_VGA_SWITCHEROO=y
```

And yet:

```
> sudo ls /sys/kernel/debug/
acpi  bdi  bluetooth  dri  extfrag  gpio  ieee80211  kprobes  mce  mmc0  regmap  regulator  sched_features  suspend_stats  tracing  usb  wakeup_sources  x86
```

I am NOT using the fglrx driver. Here is the output of `lspci; glxinfo | grep renderer`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev b4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev b4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev b4)
00:1c.7 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 8 (rev b4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation QM67 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Seymour [Radeon HD 6400M Series]
01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Caicos HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 6400 Series]
24:00.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): JMicron Technology Corp. IEEE 1394 Host Controller (rev 30)
24:00.1 System peripheral: JMicron Technology Corp. SD/MMC Host Controller (rev 30)
24:00.2 SD Host controller: JMicron Technology Corp. Standard SD Host Controller (rev 30)
25:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 (rev 34)
26:00.0 USB controller: NEC Corporation uPD720200 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 04)
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on AMD CAICOS
```

Both `xserver-xorg-video-intel` and `xserver-xorg-video-radeon` packages are installed.

I know there are tons of posts about hybrid-graphics already but I couldn't quite find a solution to my problem. Does anyone know why is /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo not showing?

Comment: In [Ubuntu Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics): `The vga_switcheroo mechanism will only be active when the kernel is booted with either the "modeset=1" kernel option, and/or the "nomodeset" option being absent.`. Check if isn't that the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to `/etc/fstab`:

```
none  /sys/kernel/debug debugfs defaults 0 0
```

Comment: That folder isn't empty by default. I'm almost positive trying to mount something there will fail unless the folder is actually empty.