# How to re-configure graphics from Intel integrated to Intel / ATI switchable?

Tags: drivers, ati, intel-graphics, hybrid-graphics, switchable-graphics

**Minimum goal: Ability to switch between the graphic cards without drivers re-installation. Restarting computer in the process is fine.**

There are lots of 'how to get switchable graphics to work' guides but I found none on how to configure a system for switchable graphics operation on Ubuntu from the ground up, nor explaining the current driver situation for particular computer models (integrated+discrete combinations).

Examples:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics
 http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Switchable_Graphics

My system being mature and on Intel integrated card also makes things complicated.

**System information:**
Ubuntu 12.04 amd64, installed clean with system configured to use only the integrated Intel card
[Lenovo Thinkpad T500](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Category%3aT500)

Intel GMA 4500MHD / ATI Mobility Radeon HD 3650

**Current situation:**
Mature and up-to-date system with no configuration changes to what's given above.
I've made a backup image of the system (Clonezilla) so regardless of what's written below **let's assume it's our starting point.** If something in *What I have already tried* is not clear you may as well diregard it.

**What I have already tried:**
Configuring BIOS to switchable graphics and:

1. Installing Additional Hardware drivers - returned an error.
2. Installing proprietary amd-driver-installer-12.6-legacy-x86.x86_64.run automatically - system starts to 'low-graphics mode'.
3. Tried fixing as per https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI#Manually_installing_Catalyst_12.6.2C_special_case_for_Intel.2BAC8-ATI_hybrid_graphics
4. Got lost, gave up.

**BIOS settings:**
Please note that while configuring BIOS for integrated graphics only is pretty straightforward, configuring for switchable graphics is not. Despite that if you know the driver installation part well, I'm willing to test all the BIOS settings combinations on my own.

Comment: Have you tried out this method? http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11712748 (although this has only been confirmed to work on AMD HD6xxx series and up)

Comment: @Glutanimate No, I haven't. Reason: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=12242803#post12242803

Comment: I'm heavily interested in this question. What will be the use of having it done this way.

Comment: @kmassada It's not any particular way. It's about switching graphics, that's it. I just specified that even the most primitive method is allowed, even involving computer restart. The only thing I don't want to do is installing drivers from scratch each time I'd like to use another graphics chip, as I don't think it could be defined as 'switching'. That's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not possible with AMD/ATI proprietary drivers. Please refer to [Any way to make switching between discrete and integrated graphics from the BIOS work with proprietary drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/234119/any-way-to-make-switching-between-discrete-and-integrated-graphics-from-the-bios)

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution for while googling. You have to put a script in `rc.local` specifying which VGA you want to use.

This [link](http://cisight.com/switch-off-ati-vga-in-dual-vga-with-intel-on-ubuntu-to-solve-overheat-problem/) explains everything.

I will post important notes here:

1. First install needed driver and script from git

   ```
   sudo apt-get install git && cd ~/  
   git clone https://github.com/mkottman/acpi_call.git  
   cd acpi_call && make  
   sudo insmod acpi_call.ko  
   chmod a+x test_off.sh
   ```
2. de-activate ATI VGA

   ```
   sh test_off.sh
   ```
3. Now you can check if your ATI VGA is already disabled by `lspci -vnnn | grep VGA`.
   It will show the following output:

   `00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0116] (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
   01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: ATI Technologies Inc NI Seymour [AMD Radeon HD 3650M] [1002:6760] (rev ff) (prog-if ff)`
4. If it works, to make this run at boot, edit `/etc/rc.local`:

   ```
   sudo insmod /acpi_call/acpi_call.ko
   sudo sh /acpi_call/test_off.sh
   ```
5. Also, remove radeon blacklisting by editing `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`:

   ```
   #blacklist radeon
   ```

   You should have `xorg.conf` like this to make VGA detectable :

   ```
    Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier "aticonfig Layout"
    Screen 0 "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0" 0 0
    EndSection

    Section "Module"
    Load "glx"
    EndSection

    Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-0"
    Option "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
    Option "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
    Option "DPMS" "true"
    EndSection

    Section "Device"
    Identifier "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
    # Driver "fglrx"
    BusID "PCI:1:0:0"
    EndSection

    # Section "Screen"
    # Identifier "Default Screen"
    # DefaultDepth 24
    # EndSection

    Section "Screen"
    Identifier "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0"
    Device "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
    Monitor "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-0"
    DefaultDepth 24
    SubSection "Display"
    Viewport 0 0
    Depth 24
    EndSubSection
    EndSection
   ```

Note: To activate ATI/AMD radeon VGA again: 
**Just comment what we've added to rc.local**

**Solution 2**

I found this solution from askubuntu.com, I might be easier to put into practice:

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159278/vga-switcheroo-and-intel-hd-3000-on-ubuntu-12-04) assumes using vga_switcheroo.

Add this to `/etc/fstab`:

```
none  /sys/kernel/debug debugfs defaults 0 0
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I won't be able to test it before the bounty ends (tomorrow). Have >you< actually tested it? Are you sure the procedure addresses this particular question? Isn't it the case that the authot from http://cisight.com always uses his Intel graphics, regardless of having his ATI/AMD switched on or off?

Comment: first, Sorry I don't have right now a dual graphics card to test it. Second, I Noted how to re-enable ATI again, You can choose which card you want.

Comment: Since the bounty is ending  soon and I can't confirm your answer validity, I'll mark your quwstion and you'll get the bounty. However if the answer turns out invalid, I'll ask moderator to unmark it, if possible.

Comment: Error in Solution1: After ~/acpi_call$ chmod a+x test_off.sh I get the following error: 
chmod: cannot access `test_off.sh': No such file or directory . No other errors up to this point.