# Any way to make switching between discrete and integrated graphics from the BIOS work with proprietary drivers?

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, fglrx, switchable-graphics

**What I would like to be able to do:**

I would like to be able to switch between my dedicated graphics card (AMD) and integrated chip (Intel) from the BIOS, that means:

*Restart → BIOS: set to integrated Intel enabled (only) → boot*

or

*Restart → BIOS: set to discrete AMD enabled (only) → boot*

This type of primitive switching works fine when running on open source drivers. However, as soon as I install `fglrx`, switching from AMD to Intel from the BIOS breaks the session and the system falls back to low-graphics mode on boot-up.

**What I did:**

1. fresh system, open source drivers with Intel enabled
2. switched to AMD = no problemo!
3. switched to Intel = no problemo!
4. (the above repeated few times and tested for performance
   issues)
5. installed proprietary AMD drivers per
   http://www.unixmen.com/ubuntu-12-10-and-amd-catalyst-problem-solved/
   (PPA) ⇒  working fine after restart!
6. switched to Intel ⇒ broken configuration, i.e. system boots to
   2D/fallback mode!

**Why do I need it?**

First of all, it's a matter of my curiosity. More importantly though, getting this thing to switch on AMD proprietary would be huge for me.

[I was asking about AMD/Intel switching a while ago](https://askubuntu.com/questions/189540/how-to-re-configure-graphics-from-intel-integrated-to-intel-ati-switchable) and while I got the answer, 1) it doesn't work 2) I can't contact the author of the answer 3) I suspect the answer is overcomplicated.

In summary I need help either with this question or with the old one linked above.

**System information:**

Ubuntu 12.04 amd64, installed clean 
Lenovo Thinkpad T500
Intel GMA 4500MHD / ATI Mobility Radeon HD 3650

Comment: Hi, I am facing a similar situation to yours (AMD HD5650/Intel core i5 integrated graphics). I have yet to find a solution for this problem, but I took the liberty to modify your question a bit for clarity's sake. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: Side question: Why are you using a PPA for the proprietary drivers? `fglrx` is available in Ubuntu official repositories

Comment: @MestreLion Because I need fglrx-legacy, not fglrx. Please refer to http://askubuntu.com/questions/204410/how-do-i-install-the-latest-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-in-ubuntu-12-10-quantal/206204#206204

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no solution for this problem. You can read more about it here: http://phoronix.com/forums/showthread.php?78813-Simple-graphics-switching-through-BIOS/ I'll ask moderators to re-open the question when a viable solution comes into light.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried this with an AMD adapter, but your issue is common to integrated vs. discrete Nvidia graphics setups as well (tested on a Lenovo Thinkpad T510s).

Under normal circumstances, an open source graphics driver is automatically selected by the X server during boot based upon your adapter selection in BIOS -- integrated vs. discrete.

When enabling proprietary drivers while the discrete adapter is in use, an Xorg configuration file is created in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` in order to explicitly tell the X server to use the proprietary driver.  While this configuration file exists, X will use the driver specified in it rather than auto-detecting your hardware setup.  You can see how this would be problematic when you switch back to your integrated graphics adapter; the AMD/Nvidia proprietary driver is still specified in the `xorg.conf` file.

The way to safely revert back to your integrated graphics adapter is to delete the `xorg.conf` file:

```
$ sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

Alternately, you may rename the file such that it can no longer be found by X:

```
$ sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.backup
```

On your next boot, when no `xorg.conf` file is detected, the X system will again auto-detect your hardware configuration and load the appropriate open source driver.

Comment: Didn't work. After proprietary dr. installation I have no xorg.conf file and I still don't have it after switching back to Inel integrated, so there's nothing to delete or move. Must be something else.

Comment: Is there a directory like `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d`?  As well, are you sure it is the Intel adapter in use, and with the correct driver?  You can check by executing `lshw -c video` and looking for the line of output starting with "configuration".  This should list the driver in use.

Comment: The driver vendor is indicated Intel Corporation, version 07. Like I said there are no xorg.conf* files in /etc/X11/ The /etc/X11/ directory itslef does exist of course.

Comment: The bounty ends tomorrow...

Comment: Pretty sure that for using the fglrx drivers you need a xorg.conf file as specified on this answer...

Comment: @BrunoPereira The current recommended installation procedure of fglrx-legacy (via PPA) doesn't give xorg.conf. I'm not proficient enough to continue the investigation on my own. I need instructions. Note: sudo amdconfig --initial doesn't produce xorg.conf. I didn't try sudo amdconfig --adapter=all --initial because, as stated, my system BIOS is configured for EITHER integrated OR discrete, so always single graphics adapter.

Comment: @Bucic Thank you for the bounty! If `lshw` is showing the Intel adapter in use, then I'm wondering whether the AMD discrete adapter is really being enabled.

Comment: @mirzmaster Intel was indicated because at that point i had it selected in BIOS. When I select discrete in BIOS, AMD is indicated. Everything is fine in this regard i.e. I've tested that in system adapter is activated strictly as selected in BIOS. Please move on.

Comment: Reminder: currently we're at step 6 and I have no /etc/X11/xor g.conf.* files to delete from my system.