# Unity crashing with amd drivers

Tags: drivers, graphics, ati, fglrx, crash

I recently installed Ubuntu. I am currently trying to install graphics drivers for my GPU. But my case may be a bit different, I have an APU A10-7770K and a graphics card Radeon R7 250X. I tried many, many times to get my rig run properly, with the package manager : `apt-get install fglrx`, `apt-get install fglrx-updates`. With the automated installer provided by AMD for Linux, with the packages, downloaded from AMD and using the "Additional Drivers". They all install successfully but upon starting the OS, my GUI(Unity) crashes. I've been trying to edit the xorg.conf file, but nothing works. Every time upon error I uninstall all the drivers from recovery mode with networking and root access with `apt-get purge fglrx*`. I think, maybe the APU is conflicting with the driver. Because these drivers are compatible with the GPU: R7 250X but not the GPU in the APU and if the APU GPU is set to be default this is where the problem may be. Unfortunately I do not know how to check it nor set it. Please give your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many tries and errors I reached a conclusion. Nowadays desktop distoros based on Linux  are not compatible enough with all the possible combinations of hardware. I strongly believe that one day a Linux distro with the compatibility of Windows, ease of Mac, speed and power of open source kernel will be made. But today is not the day, so the only possible solution to my answer here is to go back to Windows... I just bought Win 8.1 license. Maybe I will dual boot with Debian. For now, farewell  Ubuntu. Looking forward for more compatibility. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had the same problem some time ago. The only way I could fix this is turning off CPU integrated video in BIOS. I have Intel Core i5.

As I remember, there is a problem in working in gybrid mode, when it tries to use integrated processor under low load.

So enter BIOS and try to turn integrated graphics off.

Comment: In my UEFI BIOS I have set in North Bridge Configuration - **Primary Graphics Adapter** : _PCI Express_ , **Onboard Graphics**  :  _Disabled_  ,  **IOMMU**  :  _Disabled_  .  But `lspci -vnn | grep VGA` command returns the both video cards, so the integrated GPU is still visible, am I missing something ?

Comment: No, you don't.  May be you did not save changes in BIOS? Anyway, in couple hours I will check my computer, may be I got the same.

Comment: I did save the changes. ..

Comment: BTW I found that on every reboot my xorg.conf file gets rewritten.

Comment: It is not needed anymore. So it may be overwritten everytime as X11 autodetects params.  You may configure by your own by `X -configure` or edit options in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d`. Good answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/4662/where-is-the-x-org-config-file-how-do-i-configure-x-there)

Comment: Still not working...

Comment: When I run `sudo aticonfig  - -list-adapters ` I see that my integrated graphics card is set to be default.

Comment: I cant find a way to change the default setting to be the discrete GPU.

Comment: Some explanations related to situation http://askubuntu.com/a/235364/329006

Comment: Can't seem to find nothing useful. My gui crashes everytime. I can't switch from integrated to descrete in UEFI.

Comment: I played a bit with the settings in UEFI. Yes, my PC is running with the main GPU , but the integrated GPU is still visible to the system, although the Onboard Graphics  setting is set to disabled .

Comment: Sorry for long answer, could not check before.


   `lspci -vnn | grep VGA
    01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Barts XT [Radeon HD 6870] [1002:6738] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])`

So I do have only AMD/ATI activated. Do not know, why integrated video wont turn off. May be you need to update BIOS.

Or need to find out how to make them work both. I could not. So for me the only correct way was to turn Intel integrated video off.